Do writes to "$GITHUB_ENV" persist across jobs you depend on which fire before you?
If two jobs foo and bar are created in GitHub Actions and bar needs: foo, will bar see the writes to $GITHUB_ENV that foo did? Will it then "inherit" that environment?

No
In the following snipped the get_env job will return 12345.
env:
  my_output: 12345

jobs:
  set_env:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set Output
        id: step1
        run: echo "my_output=77foobar77" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
      - name: Use Output
        run: echo "${{ env.my_output }}"

  get_env:
    needs: set_env
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Use Output
        run: echo "${{ env.my_output }}"

